# Unable to get posted file name in GridView when uploading file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Unable to get posted file name in GridView when uploading file.
Here is what I tried with.

ASPX File content is shown below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVProtocol" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
                                HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="DGList" HeaderStyle-CssClass="DGHeader"
                                RowStyle-CssClass="DGRow" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="DGRowAlt" OnRowCommand="GVProtocol_RowCommand"
                                OnPageIndexChanging="GVProtocol_PageIndexChanging" Height="90px" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SL NO" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="20">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# (( ( GridView ) ( ( GridViewRow ) Container ).Parent.Parent ).PageSize + Container.DataItemIndex + 1)- 15 %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>                                                                                                                     
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="NAME" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Unit" DataField="UNIT" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Standard Value" DataField="STANDARD_VALUE" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload XML" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" Text="upload" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="upload" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FilePath" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="200">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFilePath">-</asp:Label>                                                 
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownload" runat="server" CommandName="download" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>                                                                                                                                 
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>

                                <PagerStyle CssClass="pagerStyle" />
                                <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="DGHeader" />
                                <RowStyle CssClass="DGRow" />
                                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="DGRowAlt" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

This is the CodeBehind file for the above ASPX content:

```
protected void GVProtocol_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int Index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            if (e.CommandName == "upload")
            {
                string strFilePathTemp = Server.MapPath("~/ProtocolCommunication/");

                //int Index = ((GridViewRow)((sender as Control)).NamingContainer).RowIndex;



                LinkButton lbDownload = (LinkButton)GVProtocol.Rows[Index].FindControl("btnDownload");
                lbDownload.Text = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'>";
                Label lblFilePathTemp = (Label)GVProtocol.Rows[Index].FindControl("lblFilePath");
                lblFilePathTemp.Text = strFilePathTemp;
                FileUpload fileUpload = (FileUpload)GVProtocol.Rows[Index].FindControl("FileUpload");

                if(fileUpload != null)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                    fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(strFilePathTemp + fileName);
                }


            }
            if (e.CommandName == "download")
            {
                Label lblFilePathTemp = (Label)GVProtocol.Rows[Index].FindControl("lblFilePath");
                string fileNameAndPath = lblFilePathTemp.Text.ToString();


                string file = Path.GetFileName(fileNameAndPath);
                Response.ContentType = ContentType;
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(fileNameAndPath));
                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/ProtocolCommunication/"));                    
                Response.End();
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }              
    }
```

Looking for possible solution for the above problem.

Comment: are you getting FileUpload Control..??

Comment: yes,,but not getting the posted file,,getting null value

Comment: Hi,,I got solution,,by using '<asp:updatePanel>' with postbacktrigger to hold the control ID's which are dynamically created in girdview. and using this you can upload and download files to any of the gridview row..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution,,by using
 asp:updatePanel control with postbacktrigger to hold the control ID's which are dynamically created in girdview. and using this you can upload and download files to any of the gridview row.